# ActionBarSherlock & HoloEverywhere - Forcing Overflow?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, actionbarsherlock, android-holo-everywhere

I have a simple question.
For my android app, I'm planning on using the ActionBarSherlock and HoloEverywhere libraries. Everything works well besides one thing: Forcing the overflow menu onto older devices. Without the HoloEverywhere project, the forced overflow works perfect with the following line:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.ForceOverflow"
```

My problem is, I can't get the Forced Overflow to work when I apply

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.HoloEverywhereDark.Sherlock.ForceOverflow"
```

Eclipse gives me an error saying that there's no resource found that matches the given name. It works nice without the .ForceOverflow. 
Is this just not supported by HoloEverywhere or is there a way to manually do it myself?

Comment: what is HoloEverywhere, I can't find any link ?

Comment: HoloEverywhere is a great project library. It basically let's you use the 4.x Holo theme on older devices running 1.x and 2.x.
https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Extend a `HoloEverywhere` theme and add:

```
<item name="absForceOverflow">true</item>
```