# Creating an Options Menu not working for me

Tags: android, android-layout, menu

Following the instructions at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html I try to add an option menu to my existing Activity by first creating an xml as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/new_game"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_new_game"
          android:title="@string/new_game"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/help"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_help"
          android:title="@string/help" />
</menu>
```

and then inflating the menu in the activity as

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.game_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Apparently that is not sufficient. So what am I missing in the code? I am testing with Samsung S5.

My activity `extends FragmentActivity`, in case that matters.

Comment: Did you try pressing the S5's menu key? Try pressing the multitasking key. Press and hold it in until and see if the menu pops up.

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be with the theme your activity is using. Try to use a theme which has actionbar in it. I suppose, Theme.Holo.ActionBar.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure the menu is there but you are not able to just see it. The above code, as far as I know, has no problem. The problem might be with the phones with a menu key and the ones without it. There have been infinite discussions over that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20444596/how-to-force-action-bar-overflow-icon-to-show), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9286822/how-to-force-use-of-overflow-menu-on-devices-with-menu-button) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13307214/how-to-force-overflow-menu-in-actionbar-using-actionbarsherlock-on-4-0-devices), and also [here](http://blog.vogella.com/2013/08/06/android-always-show-the-overflow-menu-even-if-the-phone-as-a-menu/). One of the hacks that people use to force their menu options in the action bar overflow is

```
try {
        ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(this);
        Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class.getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");
        if(menuKeyField != null) {
            menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);
            menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // Ignore
    }
```

Put the above code in the `onCreate()` of your application class. You are using S5, so try long pressing the multitasking key. That enables the [menu options in S5](http://www.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s5-menu-button-hidden).

Comment: what library does Field belong to?